# How to prevent strings from beeing multiple times in PROGMEM

Tags: c++, assembly, avr, progmem

I am trying to safe some program space by trying to reduce the count strings in progmem. So i started to put all stings which are needed multiple times into a file with a namespace:

```
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>
#ifndef __PSTRINGS__
#define __PSTRINGS__
namespace p_strings
{
//golbal
const char right_arrow[] PROGMEM = ">";
const char procent[] PROGMEM = "%";
const char start[] PROGMEM = "Start";
const char speed[] PROGMEM = "Speed: ";
//... more here
}
#endif
```

I am using the strings by including them into the file where i need them and for example call `Display::out_p(1, 0) << p_strings::right_arrow;`. Which reads the byte out of the progmem and put them at the right position of the display.
But if i look into the `.Iss` i see that they are still included multiple times into the ASM.

```
000000a8 <_ZN9p_stringsL5startE>:
      a8:   53 74 61 72 74 00                                   Start.
...
000000de <_ZN9p_stringsL5startE>:
      de:   53 74 61 72 74 00                                   Start.
```

So i guess this isnt the right solution to safe storage.

My questions now are:

1. Why does it still included (in the asm) multiple times? (Maybe some preaty simple failur of my thinking)
2. How to i create "something" which prevents this? (Do i need somehow a class which i pass as reference?)

If more information is needed let me know.

Comment: As written in the question, I'd expect that to give you linker errors for duplicate symbols. Are the declarations inside a nameless namespace inside `namespace p_strings` (or declared `static`)? (By the way: `__PSTRINGS__` is a reserved symbol that you're not supposed to use unless you're a standard library or compiler.)

Comment: The file is like included in the question above. They are not static just const inside of a namespace in global space. I dont use __ PSTINGS __. Yes they are inside of a nameless namespace inside of the p_string namespace if i understand that right

Comment: I tried making them static which did not change anything of the outcome.

Comment: Your include guard declares a `__PSTRINGS__` macro, but that is just a timebomb that may explode with the next compiler update -- the error would look different if it were the cause. The nameless namespace has the same effect as declaring them static. Anyway, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files-in-c should answer this in great detail.

Comment: Thanks alot. Ill change the guard for sure. didnt see it. Lets see if i can get it work.

Comment: link time optimizations will do that for you.

Comment: It doesn't. It's optimize with o3 and it is still multiple times in the asm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, a `const` variable has internal linkage by default (as if it was `static`)—which normally means that each translation unit (each `.cpp` file) gets its own copy. This may very well be why you're seeing them multiple times.

What you'd want to do is declare the variables as `extern`, and then define them in exactly one source file.

Comment: No, they're not static by default. That's a consequence of the nameless namespace OP didn't put into the code in the question but mentioned in the comments.

Comment: @Wintermute OK, it's not static by default, but it *does* have internal linkage by default. C++11 3.5/3: "A name having namespace scope has internal linkage if it is the name of ... a variable that is explicitly declared `const` or `constexpr` and neither explicitly declared `extern` nor
previously declared to have external linkage."

Comment: So what I have todo is as already mentioned to declare them external in the namespace and declare them once in a cpp and just use them as I do?

Comment: @BennX That should be it. `extern` declaration in the header, definition in one `.cpp` file.

Comment: @BennX It needs to be `extern const char right_arrow[]` in the header as well, and needs to be inside the namespace in the `.cpp` file.

Comment: yea already noticed thanks. To use the PROGMEM it need to be: `extern PROGMEM const char right_arrow[];`and in the cpp `const char p_strings::right_arrow[] = ">";`

Thanks!